# How do I fix 307 redirect from using Python Flask?

Tags: python, html, http, flask, https

I'm creating a web page by using python flask.
From the selection page, whenever user selects specific category, then it generates a power calculation.

From the category lists, the first three categories always make:

[image: 307 redirect warning page.]

However, the remaining categories after fourth one does not make warning and gives straight calculated power.

This is my code to return calculated power from `PracticePower` class.
Do you have any idea how to get rid of that warning message on first three categories?
The other remaining categories use the same code as above.

I have tried to change some form action, but it did not work

```
@app.route ('/Practice1/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def create22():
    print('request.method', request.method)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        content = '''
            <form action ="/Practice1" method = 'POST'>
                <p><h1>Practice 1 Calculation Page </h1></p>
                <p><label for = "LTE"> Choose BW of LTE: </label>
                <select name = "LTE" id = "LTE">
                    <option value = "0">0</option>
                    <option value = "5">5</option>
                    <option value = "10">10</option>
                    <option value = "15">15</option>
                    <option value = "20">20</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <p><label for = "NR"> Choose BW of NR: </label>
                <select name = "NR" id = "NR">
                    <option value = "0">0</option>
                    <option value = "5">5</option>
                    <option value = "10">10</option>
                    <option value = "15">15</option>
                    <option value = "20">20</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <p><input type = "submit" value = "Check"</p>
            </form>
        '''
        return content
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        LTE = int(request.form['LTE'])
        NR = int(request.form['NR'])
        return PracticePower.Practice_calculation(LTE,NR)
```